# SQL - Slope, intercept, and error of linear regression with few data points

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

Where `Value_M0` is the value of the `Client_ID` at `YearMonth` date, `Value_M1` is the value of `Client_ID` at `YearMonth - 1`, `Value_M2` is the value of `Client_ID` at `YearMonth - 2`, and so on (you can see this relationship with `Client_ID = A` for his respective `202001, 201912` dates.

I'm looking to get in additional columns the next parameters: the intercept, slope, and error of a linear regression (three different columns) for each `Client_ID` and `YearMonth` (together they are the key of the table). For example:

- The intercept, slope, and error for the first row considering `Value_M0` as the most recent and `Value_M4` as the oldest (ignoring NULL values). ALWAYS `Value_M0` will be the most recent value, and `Value_M4` will be the oldest.
- If its not too complicated, I would like to define the columns to consider to compute the parameters. For example, I would like to create `Slope_M2_M0`, `Intercept_M2_M0`, `Error_M2_M0`, where those parameters will be computed only considering the variables `Value_M2`, `Value_M1`, and `Value_M0`.

I hope I was clear, if not please ask for clarification.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: SQL Server is not the optimal tool for this problem.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit? How complicated it would be?

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right. And my POV is A) Data is not in relational format B) "Excel" tables to store results in a DB use up a lot of space for no real gain. - The better approach is to store year/month and clientid with the period's result, then create view(s) to transform the results. Performance depends on number of rows and complexity of calculation. IF indeed to use SQL Server.

Comment: I actually show how to do this in a database that does not support these functions in my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  The purpose of that example is more to show how we can contort databases to do some things.  But it is non-trivial.